# Can I load a jar from the script (and use it)

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I have a Java program which runs Nashorn (by default).

```
engine = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(someCode); // how can I have 'someCode' to load some jar ?
```

I want to know if it is possible for **a Nashorn/JavaScript to load a new jar** (let's say from a URL) and then access it.

In the snippet above, it means: what is *'someCode'* going to look like ?

I found a possible solution here:
https://github.com/lorenzoongithub/nudge4j/blob/master/docs/proxy/load.examples.js#L152-L158

but it feels a bit hackish.
Besides, it looks like it might break on Java 9

https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/5z3tmf/a_blooming_good_tostring/devarrt/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

But at the moment you'll only have to use Class loaders.
The hackish way it is